# How can i compare two fields in mySQL and return the result

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to compare two fields of the same table, the fields names are 'start' and 'end'. For both start and end fields I have values 00 to 23 stored. for example

```
----------------
| start|end|name
===============
 00     00   a
 01     01   b
 02     02   b
 03     03   w
 .      .
 .       .
 23     23   v
```

so what I am looking is that i needs to compare the start and end fields and choose the corresponding name.

For example,

if customer chooses start as 01 and end as 10, then I needs to list all the name in between this values.

How can I do it in MySQL Query?

Comment: How do you determine the letter that you have in that result table? Where do you get it from? Are there two tables involved? Can you name them and describe their structure?

Comment: Can you provide a sample output?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I didnt understand it so good but sounds like should try something like this

```
SELECT name FROM your_table WHERE( start >= RANGE1 AND end <= RANGE2)
```

Comment: I tend to agree this seems to match the request.  The request is odd in that why bother looking at start and end if they are the same values wouldn't a between work?  maybe a distinct is needed since b seems to repeat in the example

Comment: @xQbert probably the between is also another valid way, but since there are 2 fields, you will need to make 2 betweens (unless you can make a between for applying both fields)

Answer (score 0):

This will do it

```
select * from stuff 
where start>= '01'
and end <= '03'
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f70bb/4